# Problem with \setbox

Tags: boxes, plain-tex

I wrote the following box, which contains my name displayed vertically:

```
\setbox0\vbox{\hbox{M}\hbox{a}\hbox{t}\hbox{t}\hbox{e}\hbox{o}}
```

I'd like to dysplay it twice in a line, so I wrote:

```
\line{\hss \box0 \hss \box0 \hss}
```

But there is a problem:  \box0 appears only once!  I see only one copy of my name!

Instead, if I write

```
\line{\hss \vbox{\hbox{M}\hbox{a}\hbox{t}\hbox{t}\hbox{e}\hbox{o}} \hss \vbox{\hbox{M}\hbox{a}\hbox{t}\hbox{t}\hbox{e}\hbox{o}}\hss}
```

I get the desired output.

What's wrong with the use of `\setbox0` or `\box0`?

(All is done under plain TeX.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\box` also clears the box register. Use `\copy` instead.

```
\line{\hss \copy0 \hss \copy0 \hss}
```

I would use `\hfill` instead of `\hss`. Then TeX will throw an overfull `\hbox` warning, if the place is not sufficient.

A centered version can be achieved via `\halign`:

```
\setbox0\vbox{\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr M\cr a\cr t\cr t\cr e\cr o\cr}}
\line{\hfill \copy0 \hfill \copy0 \hfill}
\bye
```

> [image: Result]

### Smaller space between letters

The following example uses different methods to reduce the space between the letters. The first boxes 0, 2, 4 (even numbered boxes smaller than ten are scratch boxes for local assignments) keep the distance between the baselines constant. Box 0 is the unmodified version. Box 2 shrinks the `\baselineskip` according to egreg's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249124/problem-with-setbox/249126?noredirect=1#comment592813_249126). The extreme is in box 4,
where the maximum letter height is measured with the result that the two "t"s are in touch.

The boxes 6 and 8 keep the distance between the letters constant. Because of `\baselineskip=0pt`, TeX switches to set `\lineskip` instead. It's default value is `1pt`. Box 8 finally does not leave any space between the letters.

```
\def\test{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr M\cr a\cr t\cr t\cr e\cr o\cr}}

\setbox0\vbox{\test}
\setbox2\vbox{%
  \advance\baselineskip-2pt\relax
  \test
}
\setbox4\hbox{atteo}
\setbox4\vbox{%
  \baselineskip=\ht4
  \lineskiplimit=0pt
  \test
}
\setbox6\vbox{%
  \baselineskip=0pt
  \test
}
\setbox8\vbox{%
  \baselineskip=0pt
  \lineskip=0pt
  \test
}

\line{\hfill\copy0 \hfill\copy2 \hfill\copy4 \hfill\copy6 \hfill\copy8 \hfill}
\bye
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you!  And if I want to leave less space between letters?  What is the equivalent of `\raise` that can be used in vertical mode?

Comment: @Matteo `\vbox{\advance\baselineskip-2pt\halign...`

Answer (score 9):

`\box` empties the box, you need `\copy0` not `\box0`.