# How to stop \newsavebox giving me bad boxes warnings or how to use better names with \setbox?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, memoir, boxes, badness

The original answer from [list of figures and tables when there are no figures or tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234398/list-of-figures-and-tables-when-there-are-no-figures-or-tables), does not give me any bad box warnings:

```latex
\def\wheninteresting#1{%
\setbox0\vbox{#1}%
\ifdim\ht0>35pt
\unvbox0
\fi}
```

However, an updated version from [How to dynamically calculate the height of an empty list of things?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515757/how-to-dynamically-calculate-the-height-of-an-empty-list-of-things), which uses `newsavebox` keeps giving me several bad boxes warnings

```
\newsavebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}
\newsavebox{\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty}

\newcommand{\whenlistisnotempty}[2]{
  \savebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}{%
    \vbox{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty}{%
    \vbox{\large\contentsname\\%
        [+\baselineskip]\\[+\afterchapskip]\\[+\midchapskip]\\}%
  }%
  \typeout{The height of the list '#1'
      is '\the\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty'
      from '\the\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty'}%
  \ifdim\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty>\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty%
    \usebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}%
  \fi%
}
```

Console:

```
) (test3.toc) (test3.lof)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--26

The height of the list 'List of Figures' is '131.77776pt' from '103.84pt'

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 26--27
[][]
(test3.lot)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 30--30

The height of the list 'List of Tables' is '117.27776pt' from '103.84pt'

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--31
[][]
```

I would like to keep using the `\newsavebox` answer because it is very much clearer to read than the answer using `\setbox0`. Can the answer using `\newsavebox` be changed to stop giving bad box warnings or can the answer using `\setbox0` become clearer to read?

Minimal example with bad boxes using `\newsavebox`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\newsavebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}
\newsavebox{\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty}

\newcommand{\whenlistisnotempty}[2]{
  \savebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}{%
    \vbox{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty}{%
    \vbox{\large\contentsname\\[+\baselineskip]\\[+\afterchapskip]}%
  }%
  \typeout{The height of the list '#1'
      is '\the\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty'
      from '\the\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty'}%
  \ifdim\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty>\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty%
    \usebox{\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\whenlistisnotempty{\listfigurename}{
\listoffigures
}

\whenlistisnotempty{\listtablename}{
\listoftables
}

\chapter{First section}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Figure
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

## Update

After @DavidCarlisle comment, I tried using `\vbox`, but it did not worked and the warnings still showing up:

```latex
\newbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty
\newbox\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty

\newcommand{\whenlistisnotempty}[2]{%
  \setbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty\vbox{#2}%
  \setbox\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty\vbox{%
    \large\contentsname\\%
        [+\baselineskip]\\[+\afterchapskip]\\[+\midchapskip]\\%
  }%
  \typeout{The height of the list '#1'
      is '\the\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty'
      from '\the\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty'}%
  \ifdim\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty>\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty%
    \unvbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty%
  \fi%
}
```

Although, all warnings now are `Underfull` badness, instead of `Overfull`:

```
(test3.tpc)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 48--48


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 48--48

The height of the list 'Short Table of Contents' is '137.05556pt' from '135.482
51pt'
[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test3.lof)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 54--54


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 54--54

The height of the list 'List of Figures' is '149.05556pt' from '135.48251pt'
[2] (test3.lot)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 60--60


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 60--60

The height of the list 'List of Tables' is '127.0pt' from '135.48251pt'
```

Comment: you shouldn't really be using boxes at all here, my original answer was just a "quick fix" to the questioner to fix things from where they were, but anyway since you need  to unbox it you should use `\setbox\whatevername\vbox`... if you do this not `\savebox` (which is `\setbox\whatevername\hbox`.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried that, but it did not worked. I updated the question with my new code. Can you check if I did what you said right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addition to @DavidCarlisle comment, I manage to fully fix them by replacing `\\[+\afterchapskip]` by `\vskip\afterchapskip`

```latex
\newbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty
\newbox\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty

\newcommand{\whenlistisnotempty}[2]{%
  \setbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty\vbox{#2}%
  \setbox\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty\vbox{%
    \large\contentsname\vskip\baselineskip\vskip\baselineskip
  }%
  \typeout{The height of the list '#1'
      is '\the\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty'
      from '\the\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty'}%
  \ifdim\ht\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty>\ht\boxBforwhenlistisnotempty%
    \unvbox\boxAforwhenlistisnotempty%
  \fi%
}
```

Console:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400)
entering extended mode
(test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bookmark.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdfescape.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bkm-pdftex.def))
(test3.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
(test3.tpc)
The height of the list 'Short Table of Contents' is '151.0pt' from '34.6825pt'
[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test3.lof)
The height of the list 'List of Figures' is '149.05556pt' from '34.6825pt'
[2] (test3.lot)
The height of the list 'List of Tables' is '127.0pt' from '34.6825pt'
[3] [4] [5] (test3.aux) )<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test3.pdf (5 pages, 32811 bytes).
Transcript written on test3.log.
```

References:

1. [What is the difference between \vskip and \vspace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/what-is-the-difference-between-vskip-and-vspace)
2. [\setbox vs. \sbox and \savebox - What are the differences I need to know about?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46480/setbox-vs-sbox-and-savebox-what-are-the-differences-i-need-to-know-about)
3. [Problem with \setbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249124/problem-with-setbox/249126)